# How can search JSON for a value key and return the nested data?

Tags: angularjs, json

The below block is my JSON. The **-KTYLrHDHt234rFDNHrm** type hashes are generated by the supplied API of the client. I think they're using Firebase.

I am passing a query in the URL which contains the pageId for each of those nested objects.

Example https://cms.app.io/edit/Nike3243

But since the hash is auto generated how can I search through all the JSON and check if the **pageId** matches my Angular route and then only return the values of the same child.

```
{
    "-KTYLrHDHtdq23423NHrm": {
        "pageCreation": "10/8/2016, 14:14:22 PM",
        "pageGallery": {
            "slider_1_img": "http://",
            "slider_2_img": "http://",
        },
        "pageId": "Nike13243",
        "pageName": "Nike Campaign 1",
        "store": "11"
    },
    "-KTYLrHDHtdqirFDNHrm": {
        "pageCreation": "10/8/2016, 12:14:22 AM",
        "pageGallery": {
            "slider_1_img": "http://",
            "slider_2_img": "http://",
        },
        "pageId": "Nike323243",
        "pageName": "Nike Campaign 2",
        "store": "12"
    },
    "-KTYLrHDHt234rFDNHrm": {
        "pageCreation": "10/8/2016, 13:14:22 PM",
        "pageGallery": {
            "slider_1_img": "http://",
            "slider_2_img": "http://",
        },
        "pageId": "Nike3243",
        "pageName": "Nike Campaign 3",
        "store": "13"
    }
}
```

So I want to return only the data of **Nike3243** but I want to return the store, the slider and the pageName. How can I do this since the KTYLrHDHt234rFDNHrm hash is something I will never know

```
cmsApp.controller('pages-edit', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    var pageIdU = $routeParams.id;

    $http.get(firebase_url+'cms/home.json'+randstatus).success(function(data) {
        $scope.pages = data;
        // this would be pageId = Nike3243
        console.log(data.pageIdURI.pageName[pageId]);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your object is called 'objTest', you could do something like this:

```
    var strPageId = 'The page id to find', objFound;

    for( var strKey in objTest ) {
       var objTemp = objTest[strKey];
       if ( objTemp['pageId'] == strPageId ) {
         objFound = objTemp;
         break;
       }
    }
    if ( typeof objFound == "object" ) {
    //Do something...object has been found!
    }
```

I actually did this:

```
$.each(data, function (bb) {
          var crossReference = data[bb].transId;
          if (crossReference==pageIdUri) {
            $scope.transNameEn = data[bb].transNameEn;
            $scope.transNameArabic = data[bb].transNameArabic;
            $scope.transCreation = data[bb].transCreation;
            $scope.transModified = data[bb].transModified;
            $scope.notes = data[bb].notes;
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier for you to simply transform the data rather than perform this search over and over. You can loop through the data once and get it in the correct format.

I would do something like:

```
var recordLookup = {};
for (var id in records) {
  var pageId = records[id].pageId;
  recordLookup[pageId] = record[id];
  recordLookup[pageId].originalId = id;
}
```

This way you can now easily look up any record by its page id.  If you need to send the data back to the server in the original form you still have that original id and can do whatever you need to in order to get it in the proper format.  This way you loop once or maybe twice, (once to make the lookup and once to revert at the end of your operation) rather than any time you need to get data out of your records.